# Can IronPython run on machine that it does not installed on?

Tags: python, wpf, ironpython

I'm new to Python (IronPython), I come from VS environment.
I want to integrate Python with WPF and I understand that IronPython is good a solution for that.

I've install IronPython on my computer, but i wonder if the project (Python+WPF) can run on a machine that IronPython is not installed on ?

My computer has:    Python, IronPython, .Net Freamwork
Target Machine has: Python, .Net Freamwork

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to distribute IronPython programs.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, you just have to include the appropriate assemblies (IronPython.dll, IronPython.Modules.dll, Microsoft.Scripting.dll, and Microsoft.Dynamic.dll) and any standard library modules you may be using with your application.